# Emplty Json payload error in calling graph api in powershell

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Below is the error and the code I have for uploading files in SharePoint Library. I am trying to upload it in a folder inside a document library. It works fine if I am uploading it in root level of library but gives below error while uploading it in a folder Releae342 inside a library. Any clue what is wrong here? This api do not require any JSON content

Code for upload:

```
Function GET-UPLOADLINK
{
    param($clientId, $clientSecret, $artifactname)
    $tokenObject = GET-TOKEN -clientId $clientId -clientSecret $clientSecret
    $uploadLinkRequestHeaders = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $uploadLinkRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    $uploadLinkRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+ $tokenObject.access_token)
    $uploadLinkRequestBody = ""
    $artifactname = "test"
    $fullname = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$($SPid)/drives/$($LibId)/root:/Release342/"    
    $comname = $fullname + $artifactname        
    $uploadLinkResponse = Invoke-RestMethod "$($comname).zip/createUploadSession" -Method 'POST' -Headers $uploadLinkRequestHeaders -Body $uploadLinkRequestBody
    $uploadLinkResponse | ConvertTo-Json
    return $uploadLinkResponse    
}
```

Error Received:

```
    Invoke-RestMethod : {
2020-12-10T14:41:58.9122308Z   "error": {
2020-12-10T14:41:58.9122643Z     "code": "BadRequest",
2020-12-10T14:41:58.9123035Z     "message": "Empty Payload. JSON content expected.",
2020-12-10T14:41:58.9124293Z     "innerError": {
2020-12-10T14:41:58.9124899Z       "date": "2020-12-10T14:41:58",
2020-12-10T14:41:58.9125415Z       "request-id": "d58a3213-cb8c-4e95-aac2-a076d36f88d9",
2020-12-10T14:41:58.9125886Z       "client-request-id": "d58a3213-cb8c-4e95-aac2-a076d36f88d9"
2020-12-10T14:41:58.9126535Z     }
2020-12-10T14:41:58.9126848Z   }
```

Comment: Its telling you that the API call is expecting the payload, its get only empty. Where are you specifying the payload in the above code? I see that $uploadLinkRequestBody = "" (is empty)!! Update it with payload and test it.

Comment: what is the meaning of payload here

Comment: If I dont give the folder name Release342 , the above code works fine and my file get uploaded in the library.